# Awk to Multiple Variables

Tags: linux, unix, awk

How would I go about assigning multiple variables values from a single ask line?

I understand:

```
VARIABLE=`awk {print $1}`
```

But how would I do multiple variables?

I need to parse a log file to compare dates and so on. Reading the file line by line in a for loop I'd want to assign the value of each word in the record so I could process it all and use the values in the script.

Comment: Is is necessary to do it all in the shell?  It seems like Perl or Python might be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why cant loop each record you need in while  or for loop

Comment: You would NOT want the read the file line by line in a shell loop. Just use awk - its the standard UNIX text manipulation tool, present in all UNIX systems. Post some sample input and expected output for help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to assign to multiple variables, but you can assign the output to an array in `bash`.

```
LOGLINE=($(awk '{...}'))
```

Then, you can refer to each the log values by column number:

```
if [ "${LOGLINE[3]}" = "Error" ] ; then ...
```